# Laravel doesn't authenticate on server but does on local machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just uploaded a project from my local machine via FTP and it seems that the live server is working differently after trying to log in.

On the live server it's not authenticating. It gets to the `__construct` on `AuthController.php` but goes right back without errors (again, on local it works fine).

I tried adding this in `Authcontroller.php`:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
    die();
}
```

And it didn't even reach it on server (it did on local).

I tried playing with the routes and instead of this:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);
```

I did this:

```
Route::post('auth/login','Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/login','Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

Didn't help on the server (local still worked fine).

I tried clearing my browser's cache, artisan cache, artisan config cache and basically anything I could find.

I tried re-uploading files from local to the server and nothing seems to work.

The most important thing here (I think) is that when I created the `postLogin` function it didn't even go in. That should be a huge tip if I actually knew what that meant.

The log didn't give me any errors.

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: laravel version 5.0.35

Comment: Ok, what systems are you running for your local and production?

Comment: does the other part of the website works? and only the login is broke? how does your login form looked like? also, did any cookie generated?

Comment: Please check the permission of Bootstrap and Storage folder.

Comment: When something works locally and won't work on the server, often it is because of case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bagus Tesa for asking to see the login file!!!
In the action of the form I added a parameter I was using for something but for some reason that's what was screwing everything up.
The important thing is that it works now...

Thanks so much!